# Add several subdocument in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

i have the following strucure:

```
{
'name':'something',
'commens':{
            'value':'something'
           }, {
            'value':'something else'
           }
}
```

My question is, how can i insert/update those subdocuments?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are you using a programming language, or are you referring to the MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the MongoDB console, you will have to use the [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-an-element-without-specifying-its-position) to update embedded documents.

```
db.yourCollection.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("4a33289ae89489"), "commens._id" : ObjectId("32321eae20fc603aee49124") }, { "$set" : { "commens.$.value" : "something else" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming 'comments' is an array, otherwise the example you posted in not a valid JSON/BSON.
For array operations, you can look : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

In update query only, you can do upsert, which will insert the document if it don't exists.